# c# Update a datagrid view every 5 seconds with a background worker from a MySQL database

Tags: c#, mysql

Here is what I'm trying to achieve:
I'm building an alert system in a windows form format in c# (visual studio). I have a windows form with a datagrid view that needs to get info from a MySQL database every 5 seconds. I am using a System.Threading.Timer and a background worker. I searched all the threads for this but nothing seems to work. The timer is working because I get a threading eror every 5 seconds so the problem must be in the background worker code. Here is the code:

```
public partial class Alerts : Form
{
    private System.Threading.Timer _timerThread;
    private int _period = 5000;
    static BackgroundWorker bgw = new BackgroundWorker();

    public Alerts()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _timerThread = new System.Threading.Timer((o) =>
        {
            // Stop the timer;
            _timerThread.Change(-1, -1);


            bgw.DoWork += bgw_DoWork;
            bgw.RunWorkerAsync();


            // start timer again (BeginTime, Interval)
            _timerThread.Change(_period, _period);
        }, null, 0, _period);


    }

    private void bgw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        string constring = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=*******";
        MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
        MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(" select * from shopmanager.alerts ;", conDataBase);

        try
        {
            conDataBase.Open();
            MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter();
            sda.SelectCommand = cmdDataBase;
            DataTable dbdataset = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dbdataset);
            BindingSource bsource = new BindingSource();

            bsource.DataSource = dbdataset;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = bsource;
            sda.Update(dbdataset);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        conDataBase.Close();
    }

    static void bgw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender,RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        // I think this is where I should be able to update the datagridview but i'm not sure how.
    }
}
```

I'm completely lost. Please help

I tried this code now but it won't recognize DataGridView1. What am I doing wrong?

```
 public partial class Alerts : Form
{
    private System.Threading.Timer _timerThread;
    private int _period = 5000;
    static BackgroundWorker bgw = new BackgroundWorker();
    private static object dbdataset;

    public Alerts()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _timerThread = new System.Threading.Timer((o) =>
        {
            // Stop the timer;
            _timerThread.Change(-1, -1);


            // Calls UpdateAlerts() that updates a datagridview with the mysql data
            bgw.DoWork += bgw_DoWork;
            bgw.RunWorkerAsync();


            // start timer again (BeginTime, Interval)
            _timerThread.Change(_period, _period);
        }, null, 0, _period);


    }

    private void bgw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        string constring = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=******";
        MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
        MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(" select * from shopmanager.alerts ;", conDataBase);


        try
        {
            conDataBase.Open();
            MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter();
            sda.SelectCommand = cmdDataBase;
            DataTable dbdataset = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dbdataset);
            BindingSource bsource = new BindingSource();

            bsource.DataSource = dbdataset;
            sda.Update(dbdataset);
            e.Result = dbdataset;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        conDataBase.Close();
    }

    static void bgw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dbdataset;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't update objects on the Form from the `DoWork` event handler; you have to update them from `RunWorkerCompleted`. The `DoWorkEventArgs e` object has an `e.Result` property that you can assign in `DoWork` (e.g., with `dbdataset`), then read it in `RunWorkerCompleted`. This tutorial may be helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/walkthrough-running-an-operation-in-the-background

Comment: You should look up Invoke. And get in the habit oll quoting the error messages you get!

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I read that already. What I would like to know is how to code it correctly (for my particular case). Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of changes I would make to your code:

- Use the `Timer` from the Windows Forms toolbox instead of `System.Threading.Timer` (it's designed to work better inside Windows Forms). Drag it onto the form, then attach an event handler to its `Tick` method to get regular updates.
- Attach the `BackgroundWorker` event handlers just once.
- Drag the BackgroundWorker component from the designer toolbox onto the form to have its lifetime managed for you; do *not* use a `static` field.
- Use `using` statements with `MySqlConnection` to clean up the resources it uses.
- Use instance methods (not `static`) so you can reference properties/fields in your `Alerts` class.

Here is an example:

```
public partial class Alerts : Form
{
    public Alerts()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // set up BackgroundWorker once
        backgroundWorker1.DoWork += OnDoWork;
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += OnRunWorkerCompleted;

        // set the timer and start it running
        timer1.Interval = 5000;
        timer1.Start();
        timer1.Tick += (o, e) => backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    // This method will run in the background every five seconds. It can't
    // access parts of the form since it is on a background thread.
    private void OnDoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        using (MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
        using (MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(" select * from shopmanager.alerts;", conDataBase))
        {
            conDataBase.Open();
            MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter { SelectCommand = cmdDataBase };
            DataTable dbdataset = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dbdataset);

            // return the results to the main form thread through this property
            e.Result = dbdataset;
        }
    }

    void OnRunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        // This will run on the main form thread when the background work is
        // done; it connects the results to the data grid.
        dataGridView1.DataSource = e.Result;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's perfect! It works awsome! Very well explained. Thanks a million

Comment: @ChristianVerner If this helped you, please accept it as the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

```
   public partial class Alerts : Form
   {
      #region Private Fields

      private static BackgroundWorker bgw = new BackgroundWorker();
      private int _period = 5000;
      private System.Threading.Timer _timerThread;

      #endregion Private Fields

      #region Public Constructors

      public Alerts()
      {
         InitializeComponent();
         bgw.DoWork += bgw_DoWork;
         bgw.RunWorkerCompleted += bgw_RunWorkerCompleted;

         _timerThread = new System.Threading.Timer((o) =>
         {
            // Stop the timer;
            _timerThread.Change(-1, -1);
            // Calls UpdateAlerts() that updates a datagridview with the mysql data

            bgw.RunWorkerAsync();

            // start timer again (BeginTime, Interval)
            _timerThread.Change(_period, _period);
         }, null, 0, _period);
      }

      #endregion Public Constructors

      #region Private Methods

      private void bgw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
      {
              DataGridView1.Invoke(new System.Action(() => 
    {DataGridView1.DataSource = e.Result;}));
      }

      private void bgw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
      {
         string constring = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=******";
         MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
         MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(" select * from shopmanager.alerts ;", conDataBase);

         try
         {
            conDataBase.Open();
            MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter();
            sda.SelectCommand = cmdDataBase;
            DataTable dbdataset = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dbdataset);
            BindingSource bsource = new BindingSource();

            bsource.DataSource = dbdataset;
            sda.Update(dbdataset);
            e.Result = dbdataset;
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
         }
         conDataBase.Close();
      }

      #endregion Private Methods
   }
```

1. you shouldn't need to subscribe to the DoWork event each time the timer fires.
2. you are never subscribing to the RunWorkerCompleted event.
3. you should assign the grids datasource to e.Result, not a private property that can't be updated by the bgw
4. not sure this will work anyway, you might want to look at Invoke. Indeed the code will throw an Cross-thread operation not valid or Target Invocation Exception.  You need to use Invoke on the grid control.